# Should I close my own question as a duplicate after upvoted and accepted answer(s)?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, duplicate-questions

I've recently asked a question regarding Java. Although I didn't understand the actual problem, another user added an answer pointing towards a question that described and answered the exact problem I was having.

My question was answered by 2 high rep users (both 100k+) and no duplicate close votes were cast. So I'm not sure if I should close it as a duplicate anyway? I'm going to need some second opinions here.

The question: [Java method arguments not applicable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57454661/java-method-arguments-not-applicable)

The duplicate: [Why is an array not assignable to Iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160081/why-is-an-array-not-assignable-to-iterable)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**

The question has already been answered and accepted, so *your* problem is solved. Marking it as a duplicate would be the best course of action here, as it directs people looking for help towards a useful thread that would probably help them more than your specific problem.

Comment: Yes I agree. Especially about the "being more usefull to future readers" part. Thanks! I've closed the question.